# Flutter: Alter auto-complete template in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

When coding for Flutter in Intellij IDEA we get standard auto complete as we build out our Widget trees.  Does anyone know how to alter these auto complete templates?  For example:

Standard auto complete would turn this:

```
chil
```

To this:

```
children: <Widget>[<cursor>]
```

I'd prefer this:

```
children: [
    <cursor>
],
```

And the comma above is a big deal in general.  I essentially want commas at the end of every line in my Widget tree and it's time consuming to always add them.  I would really like every auto-complete in that context to come with a trailing comma.

Any idea how to accomplish these alterations?

Comment: Your second point isn't valid according to dartfmt which is why it's not formatted this way.

Comment: I don't get that autocompletion you mention. You probably have some live template that does it. You can your "life templates" in IntelliJ preferences and customize them.